# How can I define large multidimensional arrays in c++ without getting this error?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

My programming knowledge is very basic but usually enough to get by for what I need it for.

I'm using visual studio and trying to define large arrays of 4 dimensions (maybe more) of size up to [20][20][20][10000].

At first I was defining an array as int array[5][5][5][900] which was working fine. I then tried defining a new array, exaclty the same size but with a different name and got an unhandled exception error on chkstk.asm Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
sub     eax, *PAGESIZE*         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.
jmp     short cs10

I tried defining as double and long double, and using a vector but seems to make no difference. I'd like to increase the size also and possible add further dimensions.

Can someone please explain a simple way to make an array like this without this happening?

The array elements only need to contain 0 or 1

Comment: This question needs more details to help us reproduce the problem - preferably a [mcve].  But at the *very* least we need to see your code.

Comment: For those curious, `int[20][20][20][10000]` is ~305MB on most machines, so should fit in RAM ok.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the array you've specified will be very large in size (20 * 20 * 20 * 900 = 7.2 million). Since that data is stored on the stack you're probably seeing a stack overflow.

You'll probably want to allocate something that large with `new` like:

```
    auto test = new int[20][20][20][900];
    test[0][1][0] = 0;

    // when you're done with it, you'll need to delete though
    delete[] test;
```

which will put it in the (much larger) heap

Comment: And additionally, since you only want to store "0" and "1", consider std::bitset, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset

Comment: Thanks for your answer, all working fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this approach:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<bool>>>> tab4;
    int n1 = 10;     // 1st dimension
    int n2 = 20;     // 2nd dimension
    int n3 = 30;     // 3rd dimension
    int n4 = 10000;  // 4th dimension

    tab4.resize(n1);
    for (auto& v : tab4)
    {
        v.resize(n2);
        for (auto& w : v)
        {
            w.resize(n3);
            for (auto& u : w)
            {
                u.resize(n4);
            }
        }
    }
    tab4[1][12][23][4000] = 9999;
}
```

**Pros:**

- This code is exception-safe and leak-free
- The vector can be easily resized, should the need appear.
- The size of each of the vector dimensions need not be compile constants
- Beginners should not be exposed to bare pointers where more robust, safe and easy to use alternatives exist.

**Cons:**

- More code is needed (this is not a serious drawback)
- The allocated memory is not contiguous (this may be of some importance to advanced users only, can be circumvented, but I'm not aware of a solution that could be advised to beginners)

**Alternative solution**

This can be used if the sizes of the vector are fixed at compile-time. One `vector` is used to allocate the memory on the heap  automatically, without resorting to bare pointers, `operator new`, etc.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // vector [10][20][30][1000]
    std::vector<std::array<std::array<std::array<bool, 10000>, 30>, 20>> tab4 (10);

    tab4[1][12][23][4000] = 9999;
}
```

I personally like `std::`, but sometimes there's too many of them. This can be achieved like this:

```
  using std::array;
  std::vector<array<array<array<bool, 10000>, 30>, 20>> tab4 (10);
```